# django rest framework : NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make a post api,
users give me `name` and `location`  and I save it
but I have a filed called `datetime` is not null,And it need to count
Please teach me how to deal with this situation

My models has 3 fileds:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

serilizers.py

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = (  'name','location' )
```

views.py

```
class DataList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.datetime = datetime.now()
```

I find `pre_save()` function on the web ,
I thought it can help me save `datetime` datetime field
But ths answer is no

How can I save the `datetime`  after I deal with it

Now I had error :

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: data.datetime
```

Comment: What Django REST framework version are you using ?

Comment: It's 3.3.0 version ,What's the difference? My python version is 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using 3.x your best option is to pass the `serializer.save()` an extra argument that will be pushed to the object's save:

```
class DataList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(datetime=datetime.now())
```

The serializer will add the `datetime` argument to `validated_data` used to create the instance.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another issue.I have to filter the ````name```` first ,the ````name```` field should not duplicate . And I should tell the client it's duplicate.  What's the appropriate way to do this ?

Comment: The best way would be to set a unique constraint on the model. Alternatively you can set a UniqueValidator on the serializer's field (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator)

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me that you're actually trying to implement the functionality of auto_now_add=True, which you're specifically prevent it at the model level.

Why isn't auto_add_now good for what you're trying to achieve: the timestamp of object creation?

Comment: The issue with auto_now / auto_now_add is they are misleading users / developers. In some cases (batch updates for ex) they won't be updated / created.

Comment: Didn't knew that. If it's a usecase (multiple create / update) than I guess that this won't be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I knew it was caused by the ORM trying to insert a null value in a non-nulable field, I was passing the right parameter to the API but the problem is with the serializer, add the datetime field to serilizers.py like this:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = (  'name', 'datetime', 'location' )
```